# create new record in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i want to create new record,But i get error:

```
TypeError: User.create(...).fetch is not a function
```

---

my UserController.js

```
create: async function(req,res,next){
await User.create({
    username: req.param('username'),
    password: 654654,
    type: 1,
  })
    .fetch()
    .then(function (new_user)
    {
      return res.ok({'user':new_user});
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.serverError({'err':err});
      }
    });
}
```

And my another question is how to validate parameter on Model.create(...) and generate custom error messages?

i use sails-hook-validation But do not work!!!!
i use sails v 1.0

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your UserController should be something like this :

```
create: async function(req,res,next)
        {

              try{
                  let new_user = await User.create({
                  username: req.param('username'),
                  password: 654654,
                  type: 1
                  })
                  .fetch();
                  return res.ok({'user':new_user});
              }
              catch(err)
              {
                 console.log(err);
                 return res.serverError({'err':err});
              }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## The create method on a mongoose schema have a callback

The first argument of it is the error (if there is), the second is the object created (here the User)

```
await User.create({
    username: req.param('username'),
    password: 654654,
    type: 1,
}, (err, user) => {
     //Use this instead of fetch
})
```